# ¿escribir una celda de excel con un formato en especifico en c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

cuando escribo un fichero con este codigo automaticamente ocupa un formato "general" para escribirlo, el problema es que si quiero escribir numeros en que empiezen con 0 este lo omite automaticamente, por ejemplo si quiero escribir 0123445 me gueardara 12345 como puedo escribir la celda con un  formato especifico desde c#

```
 Excel.Application archivoxlsx = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application(); 
        Excel.Workbook libro = archivoxlsx.Workbooks.Open("c:/Users/Edgar/Desktop/base/Libro1.xlsx", 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, true, 0, true, false, false);

        Excel.Worksheet hoja = (Excel.Worksheet)libro.Worksheets.get_Item("Hoja1");
        hoja.Cells[v,h] = cadena;



        libro.Save();
        libro.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias darle formato a la celda como texto antes de asignar el valor

```
Excel.Worksheet hoja = (Excel.Worksheet)libro.Worksheets.get_Item("Hoja1");

((Excel.Range)hoja.Cells[v,h]).NumberFormat = "@";
hoja.Cells[v,h] = cadena;
```

Entiendo que el `NumberFormat` aplica a un Range, pero si puedes hacer

```
hoja.Cells[v,h].NumberFormat = "@";
```

tambien seria valido

[How to format an Excel file using C#](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-format-excel.htm)

[How can i change the text format of a Excel Cell using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720498/how-can-i-change-the-text-format-of-a-excel-cell-using-c)